# Logic Apps getting giberish when extracting from excel

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to set up a flow that would extract data from excel files and insert into a SQL db in the cloud with properly mapped columns. I have tried multiple ways (get a row, list rows present in a table, get a table) but can't properly extract files. The most recent way I tried returns some gibberish. Anyone done that before or is there a better way to set up the desired pipeline?

[image: Logic App flow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That “gibberish” is the binary representation of the file contents you’ve ostensibly gathered from the previous step in your flow (`Get file content`).

Your error is that you’ve assumed the `File` argument of `List rows present in table` takes said binary representation and acts on it. This is not the case (and it’s not clear how you reached this conclusion in the first place); from [the documentation for the `List rows present in table` operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonlinebusiness/#list-rows-present-in-a-table):

| Name | Key | Required | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [...] |  |  |  |  |
| **`File`** | file | True | string | Select an Excel file through File Browse. |
| [...] |  |  |  |  |

While I wouldn't call this documentation *abundantly* clear, this input is configured to accept the *path* to the file you're looking to have processed by the Excel Online connector relative to the other **`Location`** and **`Document Library`** parameters.

To get this to work in totality, you'll have to swap your OneDrive trigger `When a file is created`, since it only returns the binary content of the file, and instead opt for something like [`When a file is created (properties only)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/onedrive/#when-a-file-is-created-(properties-only)) so you can wrangle its `BlobMetadata` output to pass to the associated parameters for `List rows present in table`.

Comment: appreciate the response. I am on my 4th week of learning Logic Apps so I have a long way to go. Thanks for the details